# How to animate static fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know how to animate `Fragment`s that are added dynamically via code (via `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimation` or `Fragment.onCreateAnimator`)

But I was wondering if its possible to do this with static `Fragment`s as well?

Ideally, I would like to declare my `Fragment`s in the layout file, but also animate their entrance. Right now, I am forced to go the dynamic route if I want to animate them.

Am I missing something, or is this not possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Static fragments that are declared via XML are just that - static. Animations only apply to dynamically added fragments.

Comment: seems no reason for this limitation? perhaps this could be a feature request?

Comment: @numan - the lifecycle of fragments added via XML is slightly different than that of dynamically added fragments (fragment views are created and attached within the `setContentView`, rather than as part of a separate process handled by the `FragmentManager`). As such, mixing static and dynamic fragment is almost always a bad idea. Given that, the easiest solution is to use dynamic fragments always and only have your XML include `FrameLayout` placeholders for the fragments.

Comment: inside the fragment element, i would like to see an xml attribute that is a reference to be an animation resource. that way when the fragment is inflated it could animate it. seems like a good idea to me...